# I want to round off timestamp upto second in snowflake. e.g. 2023-09-03 08:17:48.919 should be converted to 2023-09-03 08:17:49

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to round off timestamp up to second in snowflake. e.g. `2023-09-03 08:17:48.919` should be converted to `2023-09-03 08:17:49`

I tried using `TO_CHAR(column_name, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` but it is not doing roundoff.

```sql
select TO_CHAR(column_name, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from table_name
```

Comment: Adding `0.5` seconds before truncating is perhaps good enough?

Comment: What output do you want to see for the following timestamp: `2023-09-03 08:17:48.419`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, CASE WHEN DATEPART(MILLISECOND, '2023-09-03 
08:17:48.919') >= 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, '2023-09-03 08:17:48.919'), 'yyyy-MM-dd 
HH:mm:ss') AS rounded_timestamp;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

So the classic way to "round anything" is to add half the size of the unit of rounding (thus here 500 milliseconds) and then truncate towards zero. But given time tends to not be negative (yes it can, but I am not solving for that)..

we can use [DATEADD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd) and [DATE_TRUNC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc) like so:

```
select $1 as input
    ,dateadd('milliseconds', 500, input) as shift_up
    ,date_trunc('second', shift_up) as rounded_to_sec
from values 
    ('2023-09-03 08:17:48.919'::timestamp),
    ('2023-09-03 08:17:49.419'::timestamp);
```

gives the answer we are expecting.

[image]